# In React how do you handle the onChange of several select dropdowns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-select

I have a form which has several `select` as `Dropdown` components and I want the `onChange` handler to handle them individually. How can I do that?

The `Dropdown` are dynamically generated according to the number of questions from the database, hence it'll be ridiculous to write an `onChange` handler for each `Dropdown` (e.g. 30 questions)

#### component

```js
const Dropdown = props => {
  const { title, id, onChange, noSelection, options, value } = props;

  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label className="control-label" htmlFor={id}>
        {title}
      </label>
      <select
        className="form-control"
        name={id}
        id={id}
        onChange={onChange}
        value={value}
      >
        {noSelection && <option defaultValue="" />}
        {options.map(option => (
          <option value={option} key={option}>{option}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dropdown;
```

```js
class Form extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      noSelection: true,
      value,
    };

    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
  }

  handleSelect(event) {
    let target = event.target;
    let value = target.value;

    this.setState({
      noSelection: !this.state.noSelection,
      value,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="care-sub">
        <Dropdown
          title="Are a developer wanting to become a programmer?"
          id="select-care-leaver"
          onChange={this.handleSelect}
          noSelection={this.state.noSelection}
          options={['Yes', 'No']}
          value={this.state.value}
        />

        <Dropdown
          title="Do you have experience with React"
          id="select-care-estranged"
          onChange={this.handleSelect}
          noSelection={this.state.noSelection}
          options={['Yes', 'No']}
          value={this.state.value}
        />
      </div>
    );  
  }
}

export default Form
```

I expect each `Dropdown` to `onChange` individually when the user interact with them and without changing the other `Dropdowns` and without writing repeated handlers for each of them.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dynamic handling of fields, I usually give the fields a name, and handle the onChange with:

```
this.setState({
    formData: {
        ...this.state.formData,
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    },
}
```

As long as you render the selects with those names, and assign their value from the state, all will work well.

Note - I keep it in an object, so I can just get all the form data at once with `this.state.formData`.

You can assign this same onChange handler to multiple fields and they'll all work. (Note, this also works for input fields, and anything that uses `.value`)

Answer (score 0):

It is about time your `Dropdown` evolves from a functional component to a `react` component. Since you are re-using your `Dropdown` component you would need to create the `onChange` handler for it just once as a member function to `Dropdown`.

Then, everytime a `Dropdown` renders, it will use the same member function in a different `this` context.

Like so:

```
class Dropdown extends React.Component{
    onChange (e) {
        //do something based on props and value
    }

    render(){
    const { title, id, noSelection, options, value } = this.props;

    return (
        <div className="form-group">
        <label className="control-label" htmlFor={id}>
            {title}
        </label>
        <select
            className="form-control"
            name={id}
            id={id}
            onChange={this.onChange} // use the member function here
            value={value}
        >
            {noSelection && <option defaultValue="" />}
            {options.map(option => (
            <option value={option} key={option}>{option}</option>
            ))}
        </select>
        </div>
    );
    }
};

export default Dropdown;
```